# Eudyuptula Task3 meaning of "Extra cookies when you provide creative examples, especially if done in interpretive dance at your local pub."

Tags: linux, eudyptula-challenge

I am trying to go through the eudyptula challenge and I am having a hard time understanding the line

**"Extra cookies when you provide creative examples, especially if done in interpretive dance at your local pub."**

what is expected?

following is the complete challenge for context--

---

> The tasks for this round are:   – Take the kernel git tree from Task
>   02 and change the Makefile to  modify the EXTRAVERSION field.  Do this
>   in a way that  the running kernel (after modifying the Makefile,
>   rebuilding, and rebooting) has the characters  "-eudyptula" in the
>   version string.    – Show proof of booting this kernel.  "Extra
>   cookies when you provide creative examples, especially if done in
>   interpretive dance at your local pub."

is it a joke, or some kind of puzzle :D

Comment: It is expected for you to give it a good laugh, I guess, as it's obviously a joke ;)